# How to stop a running program on PyDev

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I am afraid that my question may be duplicate, but I could not find good answers for my question in stackoverflow.

I use PyDev under Eclipse. And I often run my programs by opening a Python Console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on the editor) for quick-and-easy debugging. The thing is I do not know how to stop the running program on the way. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd> did not work. If I click [terminate] icon, the whole Console disappears, in which I do not want.

Is there any ways to stop the running program and go back to command line?

Thanks

Comment: sys.exit doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl+Alt+F9 should terminate all launches, which will do the job for you.